# Error Hitch warning: 2636 msec frame time while launching COD4 Server on lan

Tags: technical-issues, hosting, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

Error Details;

I have changing server option to internet and lan they both not worked for me. While changing server to No game runs but server is not detected to other lan mates. Any help would be great thanks.

```
WARNING: unknown dvar 'bg_shock_volume_local' in file 'shock/damage_mp.shock'
WARNING: unknown dvar 'bg_shock_volume_local2' in file 'shock/damage_mp.shock'
WARNING: unknown dvar 'bg_shock_volume_ambient' in file 'shock/damage_mp.shock'
WARNING: unknown dvar 'bg_shock_volume_hurt' in file 'shock/damage_mp.shock'
WARNING: unknown dvar 'bg_shock_volume_player1' in file 'shock/damage_mp.shock'
WARNING: unknown dvar 'bg_shock_volume_player2' in file 'shock/damage_mp.shock'
WARNING: unknown dvar 'bg_shock_volume_music' in file 'shock/damage_mp.shock'
WARNING: unknown dvar 'bg_shock_volume_musicnopause' in file 'shock/damage_mp.shock'
WARNING: unknown dvar 'bg_shock_volume_mission' in file 'shock/damage_mp.shock'
WARNING: unknown dvar 'bg_shock_volume_announcer' in file 'shock/damage_mp.shock'
WARNING: unknown dvar 'bg_shock_volume_shellshock' in file 'shock/damage_mp.shock'
-----------------------------------
Hitch warning: 2636 msec frame time
```

Comment: Hm this happeneds to me to. i am still looking to find why.